# How to I change the action attribute for a html form on submit with JQuery using the jquery form plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following plugin here:

jquery.malsup.com/form/

I want to make it so that when the user clicks Submit, it changes the attribute action like:

```
$('$theform').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'theurliwant');
```

My issue is, I do not know where to put that because the JQuery Form Plugin appears to have its own handlers, and when i stick a click handler on the submit button, it seems to catch the event without going to JQuery Form Plugin's handlers.

Where can I stick the code to change the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) for your plugin. The answer is there.

Under options

> url: URL to which the form data will be submitted. Default value: value
>   of form's action attribute

There is also `beforeSubmit`

> Callback function to be invoked before the form is submitted. The
>   'beforeSubmit' callback can be provided as a hook for running
>   pre-submit logic or for validating the form data. If the
>   'beforeSubmit' callback returns false then the form will not be
>   submitted. The 'beforeSubmit' callback is invoked with three
>   arguments: the form data in array format, the jQuery object for the
>   form, and the Options Object passed into ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit.

```
beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in here (looking at the API you linked)

```
 // attach handler to form's submit event 
$('#myFormId').submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

though I'm not sure how exactly you are using the, some more code might help out.